Создание почтового аккаунта (физ) по апи автоматический
Можете подсказать есть ли такие почтовые сервисы, которые предоставляют апи не только для отправки/получения писем, но и для создания почтового аккаунта?
Есть платформа и при регистрации на платформу, нужно с этими же данными создать почтовый аккаунт. и после уже на платформе отправлять/получать письма этому пользователю

Эм, почта для домена у Яндекса, WorkSpaces у VK, Google Suite у Google и ещё куча разных сервисов. (названия продуктов могут отличаться, не очень слежу за ребрендингами)
